# Remover filtro apenas para páginas

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu precisei criar um filtro para imprimir o nome e o e-mail dos usuários dentro dos posts (`the_content`) que eles criam.

O problema é que está mostrando nos posts e também nas páginas, eu queria mostrar apenas nos POSTS, eu tentei assim e não deu certo:

```
function my_content($content) {
    $content .= "<b>Nome do comprador:</b> " . usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-author') . "<br />";
    $content .=  "<b>Email do comprador:</b> " . usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-email');
    return $content;
}

if (!is_page_template('page.php')) 
remove_filter('the_content','my_content');

else
add_filter('the_content','my_content');
```

Ele mostra certinho nos posts, mas ele está imprimindo nas páginas também (Nome do comprador: e Email do comprador:). Como remover essas impressões das páginas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente adicionar [tags condicionais](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) dentro do seu filtro,

```
function my_content($content) {

   if(is_single() || !is_page_template('page.php') || !is_page())
       $content .= "<b>Nome do comprador:</b> " . usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-author') . "<br />";
       $content .=  "<b>Email do comprador:</b> " . usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-email');

   return $content;

}
```

Comment: Raphael, estou tentando: if(is_single() || !is_page_template('template_fullwidth.php', 'page.php')) e ele não quer considerar o page.php, pq?

Comment: Para o page.php você pode utilizar `is_page()`, ficando assim sua tag condicional: `if(is_single() || !is_page_template('page.php') || !is_page())` ou `if(is_single() && !is_page_template('page.php') && !is_page())`.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o seguinte, e funcionou:

```
function my_content($content) {
```

if(is_single() || !is_page_template('template_fullwidth.php'))
       $content .= "**Nome do comprador:** " . usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-author') . "
";

return $content;
}
      add_filter('the_content','my_content');

```
  function my_content2($content) {
```

if(is_single() || !is_page_template('template_fullwidth.php'))

```
   $content .=  "<b>Email do comprador:</b> " . usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-email') . "<br />";
```

return $content;
}
      add_filter('the_content','my_content2');

Comment: **[WYSIWYG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)**?